# How do I change the keyboard shortcuts for the Window Manager in Xubuntu 13.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xubuntu

I'd like to change my Alternate Desktop shortcut in Xubuntu. How do I do that? I don't see the option under Keyboard's *Application Shortcuts*?

Answer (score 1):

Xubuntu 13.04 has two different sets of keyboard shortcuts,

- Application Shortcuts
- Window Manager → Keyboard (shortcuts)

You're simply in the wrong screen. Close out of *Application Shortcuts*, that's for starting an application with a keyboard shortcut. What you want is to go under Settings → Window Manager → Keyboard. Then you should be able to set new keyboard shortcuts.